# How to set in Report the TextBox visibility by expression in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a simple *TextBox* in my *Precision Design* related to a Field in Temporary Table. 
I need to show this TextBox only If the it value under Temporary Table is pupulated : so if the value field is pupulated (is a string) I show the Text Box , otherwise I don't show the text Box.

I need to set *Visibility* by *Expression* :

[image: set visibility]

Which is the best way forward over ?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do some research before asking questions. We are glad to help if you are stuck, but if the [first Google results](https://www.google.de/search?q=dynamics+ax+How+to+set+in+Report+the+TextBox+visibility+by+expression+in+VisualStudio%3F&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=HT_ZWNOqIoKB6ASPzZOwBQ#spf=1) for your question contain the answer, your question does not show any research effort. Also take a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Hi @FH-Inway, thanks for useful link and method. Im'm really beginner for Visual Studio, now I will research better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iif` function. Press fx button, here you can writte your code.

`iif` function evaluate a condition and return 1 of 2 options, for example, in your case you need show one value only if exist.

**check this code:**

```
=iif(fields!YourFieldName.value = "", true, false)
```

if your field is a number

```
=iif(fields!YourFieldName.value = 0, true, false)
```

This code evaluate the value of your field and only populate the value if is complete.